# NSDateFormatter Fails on Device but not on Simulator

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I've the following code. On simulator, it works. But on iPhone 6 the date variable always nil, if I changed the string to "2014-07", it works on both.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM"
let date = formatter.dateFromString("2014-08")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the time zone. Added the timezone fixed the problem

```
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
```